# Script modification(drag and drop)

Tags: autohotkey

I have simple script that looks for specified color pixel in restricted area then performs move mouse of this pixel to specified x,y coordinates it looks like this(control hold is added, because it needs to be pressed while moving stock):

```
#ifwinactive
F10::
PixelSearch, ItemX, ItemY, 1800, 600, 1700, 500, 0xFFE047, 1 , RGB FAST
if ErrorLevel = 0
Mousemove, ItemX, ItemY, 0
Send, {lbutton down}
sleep, 20
Send, {lctrl down}
Random x, 1600, 1700
Random y, 590, 655
Mousemove, x, y, 0
Send, {lbutton up}
Send, {lctrl up}
return
```

It works great but takes control over my MOUSE which I don't want, so I am trying to modify it to perform action without taking control over my mouse. I have tried to search, using controlclick but this couldn't handle dragging, then I have read about PostMessage which I don't clearly understand but I have come with this kind of script(not fully understand dll calls that's why most likely it doesn't work like intented):

```
#ifwinactive

x := 1650
y := 620

F10::
PixelSearch, ItemX, ItemY, 1900, 600, 1750, 500, 0xFFC661, 1, RGB Fast 
CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
if !hWnd := DllCall("WindowFromPoint", Int,ItemX, Int,ItemY, Ptr)
if !hWnd := DllCall("WindowFromPoint", UInt64,(ItemX&0xFFC661)|(ItemY<<32), Ptr)
if !hWnd := DllCall("WindowFromPoint", UInt64, x|(y << 32), Ptr)
    return
VarSetCapacity(POINT, 8, 0)
NumPut(ItemX, POINT, 0, "Int"), NumPut(ItemY, POINT, 4, "Int")
DllCall("user32\ScreenToClient", Ptr,hWnd, Ptr,&POINT)
ItemX := NumGet(POINT, 0, "Int"), ItemY := NumGet(POINT, 4, "Int")
if ErrorLevel
PostMessage, 0x0200, 0, ItemX&0xFFC661|ItemY<<16,, % "ahk_id " hWnd         ;WM_MOUSEMOVE
sleep, 5
PostMessage, 0x0201, 0, ItemX&0xFFC661|ItemY<<16,, % "ahk_id " hWnd         ;WM_LBUTTONDOWN
sleep, 5
PostMessage, 0x0200, 0, x|y<<16,, % "ahk_id " hWnd      ;WM_MOUSEMOVE
sleep, 5
PostMessage, 0x0202, 0, x|y<<16,, % "ahk_id " hWnd               ;WM_LBUTTONUP
sleep, 5
return
```

There is problem with this scirpt it actually act like this: Search for pixel>if it's there>perform post messages under my cursor(actually taking things under my mouse to specified x,y.
While what I want is to look for pixel, pick this pixel and move it. Is it even possible without taking control over my mouse?

EDIT!
NEW CODE

```
#ifwinactive

CoordMode, Pixel , Screen

x := 1650
y := 620
lparam := pX | (pY << 16)
lparam2 := x | (y << 16)

f10::
PixelSearch, pX, pY, 1900, 1000, 1750, 500, 0xFFE047, 1, Fast 
if Errorlevel
{
PostMessage, 0x0200, 0, %lparam%,, ahk_exe something.exe        ;WM_MOUSEMOVE
sleep, 10
PostMessage, 0x0201, 0x0001, %lparam%,, ahk_exe something.exe          ;WM_LBUTTONDOWN
sleep, 10
PostMessage, 0x0200, 0x0001, %lparam2%,, ahk_exe something.exe      ;WM_MOUSEMOVE
sleep, 10
PostMessage, 0x0202, 0, %lparam2%,, ahk_exe something.exe                ;WM_LBUTTONUP
}
return
```

Comment: This is the standard functionality in AHK and that is how it works.
If you want to do it like you're asking you need to do something beyond the capabilities of AHK as you want the operating system to perform mouse instructions without actually affecting the mouse pointer.

Comment: I have been inspired by this: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=34943
This script looks for pixel and color it - tested on sketch.io. Indeed, it still doing thing under my cursor but by the same time it color pixels when found and not taking control over my mouse.

Comment: You really should ask this question in the AHK Forum. ;)

Comment: Whether or not this is doable depends fully on how the app you're trying to make this for checks for mouse actions. If it responds to those Windows messages, then it's likely doable with them. What app are you trying to make this for? Does testing out some of those `PostMessage` commands yield any results? In any case, if it's doable, I'd be very hesitant to call it *"beyond the capabilities of AHK"*.

Comment: The second script I posted seems to ignore pixelsearch but actually does `PostMessage` inputs. App that I am going to use it with is GAME. I would call it simple bot that search for pixelcolor(gold) and pick it up to my equipment while not taking control over my mouse.

Comment: Hello, still trying - that's why I have edited my first post to add new code and problem with it.

Problem is - it would pick things under my cursor aka execute post messages whenever I hover over thing and move to "x,y". Script completly ignores PixelSearch and command to execute left mouse click + hold on "pX and pY" coordinates then move. Maybe there is something with scructure of this code?